# How to push properties of array to another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

This is my array, dataCom

```
id: "5c9e3f0aa289e606b46a7fdf"
importPrices: 500
name: "Wings spring"
owner: "5c40442b6e4425163915e5b3"
priceBaseOnBOM: 0
productId: "LXCM"
salePrices: 0
```

I want to pass some properties to new array (components) like this

```
components.push({
          salePrices: dataCom.salePrices,
          productId:dataCom.productId,
          name: dataCom.name,
          amount: dataCom.amount,
          id: dataCom.id})
```

But it's not right. I want components like this

```
components
[
    id: "5c9e3f0aa289e606b46a7fdf",
    name: "Wings spring",
    productId: "LXCM"
    salePrices: 0
]
```

Please help, thanks very much

Comment: Your desired out put is an array, and it contains keys, it is not possible else replace it with array of objects or array of single object

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var dataCom = {
  id: "5c9e3f0aa289e606b46a7fdf",
  importPrices: 500,
  name: "Wings spring",
  owner: "5c40442b6e4425163915e5b3",
  priceBaseOnBOM: 0,
  productId: "LXCM",
  salePrices: 0
};
var components = [];
var obj= {
  id: dataCom.id,
  name: dataCom.name,
  productId: dataCom.productId,
  salesPrices: dataCom.salePrices
};
for(var b=0; b<keys(obj).length;b++){
    components[keys(obj)[b]] = obj[keys(obj)[b]]
} 
console.log(components);
```

the above code will give you the following answer

**OUTPUT**

```
components
[
  id: "5c9e3f0aa289e606b46a7fdf",
  name: "Wings spring",
  productId: "LXCM"
  salePrices: 0
]
```